# Create Style for a StackPanel and its Contents

Tags: wpf, styles, resourcedictionary

I want to create a style for Stackpanels using a key. This style will be in a global ResourceDictionary for use everywhere in the application. But it should not only set the style of the Stackpanel, but also its content.

I want to use the stackpanel like this:

```
<StackPanel Style="{StaticResource GlobalStackPanelStyle}">
<Button>test</Button> <-- the button style should also be defined due to the Stackpanel style
</StackPanel>
```

How should the Resourcedictionary look like if for example all the containing buttons should be green?

Comment: Just don't do it... this site is full of problems from people who try to use WPF *how they would like it to work* rather than *how it does work*. A `StackPanel` has nothing to do with `Style` setting and doing this, while you may have some minor initial success, is only going to end in tears. Just use WPF *as it was meant to be used* and everyone will be much happier.

Comment: @Sheridan sniff, sniff... your words have touched my heart, really

Comment: @marty I already answered this yesterday, why do you still insist in the same question over and over again?

Comment: @Sheridan Am I supposed to add the style for each Button instead the surrounding Panel?

Comment: @HighCore - yes and no... yesterdays question was also about functionality - this is style only, which makes the whole thing a lot easier :)

Comment: Do yourself a favour and learn WPF properly... please take a look at the [Styling and Templating](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms745683(v=vs.110).aspx) page on MSDN for more help with this... MSDN should *always* be the first 'port of call'... *long before* coming to StackOverflow.

Comment: @Sheridan Can you explain me whats wrong with Ming Slogar's answer and how you would do the same but in the correct wpf way.

Comment: @marty, there's absolutely nothing wrong with your Ming's answer. I misunderstood your brief question and retract my initial statement. Apologies.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You would have something like this in your resource dictionary:

```
<Style TargetType="StackPanel" x:Key="GlobalStackPanelStyle">
   <Style.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="Button">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Green" />
        </Style>
    </Style.Resources>
</Style>
```

Comment: @marty Oh, yeah, I forgot about that. I'm just typing code out of my head right now; I don't have VS open.

Comment: i edited your answer to sth, which looks like it works here - thank you.

Comment: all the Buttons in the Stackpanel with the GlobalStackPanelStyle are green... so at least for me it works :)

Comment: @marty: Cool! Like I said, I don't have an IDE open, so I can't test it :)